# Sorting an array with each element contains an NSString and an NSNumber (double) entry

Tags: objective-c, collocation

I created a `NSMutableArray` with two elements; the name of a city (string at index 0) and the distance (double at index 1) from my present position.

```
for (i=0;i<[City count];++i)
{
distanceFromMe = [Location distanceFromLocation:[cityLocation]];
[a addObject:[cityNames objectatIndex:i]];
[a addObject:@(distanceFromMe)]
[cityArray addObject:a]
}
```

"Chicago", 560.34

"New York", 204.3456

"Syracuse", 50.04

I would like to sort this array by ascending distances.

"Syracuse", 50.04

"New York", 204.3456

"Chicago", 560.34

I used:

```
[cityArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES] ]];
```

But I keep getting an error of an unrecognized selector sent to instance.
In my reading it appears that the method does not need a key since there is only one `NSNumber` in the array element.  I've read a number of different threads on this but none seem to apply.

Any help would be appreciated. Using xcode obj-c not swift.

Comment: I don't use Objective-C (much at least), but it might be helpful if you could show how you're building the array(s) in question.

Comment: changed code above to include

Comment: What is the variable `a` in your code?

Comment: Just an array used to create the array of arrays "cityArray"

Comment: "I created a NSMutableArray with two elements; the name of a city (string at index 0) and the distance (double at index 1) from my present position.". Just don't. Use an array of dictionaries, or an array of custom objects. Avoid mixing different kind of objects like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @JWWalker's solution works, I'd suggest modeling this a little bit differently.

Specifically, create a class to hold the city/distance pairs:

```
@interface CityDistance
@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property(copy) NSNumber *distance;
@end

@implementation CityDistance
@end
```

Store each of your city/distance pairs.

```
CityDistance *cityDistance = [[CityDistance alloc] init];
cityDistance.name = @"New York";
cityDistance.distance = @(560.3);

NSMutableArray <CityDistance *>*cities = [NSMutableArray array];
[cities addObject: cityDistance];
```

This allows the compiler to do more type checking, you can hang business logic off the class (i.e. maybe a `-(NSNumber *)distanceFromCity:(CityDistance *)otherCity;` method?), it is less fragile (oops! Forgot to add the distance to my ambiguous array!) and makes the sorting code more clear:

```
[cityArray sortUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        CityDistance* city1 = obj1;
        CityDistance* city2 = obj2;
        return [city1.name compare: city2.name];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it without using a sort descriptor.

```
[cityArray sortUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        NSArray* arr1 = obj1;
        NSArray* arr2 = obj2;
        return [arr1[1] compare: arr2[1]];
    }];
```